# Valid values for the target path in Magento admin custom url rewrite section

Tags: magento-1.7

I am writing a script to create the **custom url rewrite** in magento. This will take a csv file as input and create the url rewrite.

I have a field in the csv file as **id_path** also.

I have one concern that do I need to follow a particular format for the id_path or I can have any unique value in this field?

Following are given in magento documentation

```
somewhere/new-page

http://magento.com
```

suppose my target_path is **destination.html** should I use **id_path** as **destination** or **destination.html** ?

Answer (score 1):

From my console

[image]

you can see id_path is a unqiue ID not related to the actual redirect rule in any way more than an ID.

The image is saying a redirect will happen when domain.com/dealerlocator is called and the final path will be domain.com/ustorelocator/location/map.